# Jquery validator in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-validate

I am trying to use Jquery validator in my cakephp project.How can i impliment validator for clientsidde validation in my project.I am confuser.I am just a starter and i have not done any validation thing axcept cakephp model validation..It is urgent. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i used jquery successfully.Here is simplre step i used for that>This is quiet simple and works fiwn.

[this](http://phppoet.blogspot.com/2011/12/cakephp-validation-using-jquery.html)

Each and every steps are discussed out there

Answer (score 0):

here is a complete demo, hopefully it will help

[jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: Thanks man for your help.I guess i have already went through that topic.But was lil confusing.I am bad with jquery> :(